# "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable" error

Tags: c#, zip

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(fu.PostedFile.InputStream)){                    
    string extractPath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
    string oldPathImg = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/RubbishData/");
    zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = *.docx", "",extractPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    var x = zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = *.png");   
}
```

The last line gives me the error "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable", I do not understand why.

Comment: I must have missed the question due to the anticipation.. What's your question? Also, try reading the API for `ExtractSelectedEntries` http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/90a4fb68-d2f7-4f28-a7e7-9a6d15d80303.htm

Comment: You could specify the type instead of using var

Comment: @AntDC `ExtractSelectedEntries` has no return, it's `void`

Comment: aha ;)  Oops.....

Comment: yes , has no return

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, there is an [Ionic API Guide](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/0c6bc5e8-bb1e-3140-3f38-09066e4e9f21.htm) for the library you are using which specifically states that all overloads of `ExtractSelectedEntries` have no return type, simply `void`

```
public void ExtractSelectedEntries(
    string selectionCriteria,
    ExtractExistingFileAction extractExistingFile
)
```

Which means your code should be like so

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(fu.PostedFile.InputStream)){                    
    string extractPath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
    string oldPathImg = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/RubbishData/");
    zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = *.docx", "",extractPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    zip.ExtractSelectedEntries("name = *.png"); // Cannot assign void to a variable, remove the assignment.
}
```

Comment: but i want this imagename in variable to resize it

Comment: Okay, well as I said, `ExtractSelectedEntries` returns void, and your question is about the error which is as a result of trying to assign void to a variable.

Comment: i've zipfile that include image and i want resize it can u help me for it ?

Comment: Post another question regarding that issue, mark this as the answer if this resolved the problem of `Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable`

Comment: Did you downvote my answer because it doesn't resolve the issue you stated in your comment, which has nothing to do with this questions problem? Answers should be marked down for being incorrect, of which this isn't - Read the API guide as linked above.